# Repository testing minimizing repetition

Tags: c#, entity-framework, integration-testing, repository-pattern

A have an application with a typical scenario data access layer (DAL):

- Data context created with Entity Framework (EF).
- Using entities generated by EF used as general DTOs for the whole application.
- DAL contains different repositories that extend a RepositoryBase abstract class, which implements basic CRUD operations; the specific repositories have only specific methods for their entity types. Repositories for entities that can be soft deleted extend a SoftDeleteRepositoryBase instead, that itself extends RepositoryBase.

To give some context, here are some classes/interfaces.

Generic repository interface:

```
public interface IRepository<T> : IDisposable where T : class
{
    void Add(T entity);
    void Update(T entity);
    void Obliterate(T entity);
    void Obliterate(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where);
    T GetById(long id);
    T GetById(string id);
    IQueryable<T> GetAll();
    IQueryable<T> GetMany(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where);
    T GetSingle(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where);
    void SaveChanges();
}
```

Repository base:

```
public abstract class RepositoryBase<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    ...
}
```

A repository for the Foo entity:

```
public class FooRepository : RepositoryBase<File>, IFooRepository
{
    // Specific methods here
    ...
}
```

How should I test the repositories? Right now I have a test class for each repository, with test methods that are very similar in all of them, as they are mostly testing generic methods from the RepositoryBase. It's obvious that I need tests for the specific methods, but for the global generic ones should I keep testing them against each different entity? I don't know if it's wise to assume that if insertion, for instance, works for Foo entities it will also work for others; however testing for each has an added overhead in terms of test creation and maintenance. Can you recommend any best practice around this?

(By the way, these are integration tests)

Thanks

Comment: Obliterate? That is first time I see Obliterate instead of Remove or Delete

Comment: There's another tool that already uses this name, and our users are very familiar with it; plus it makes you think twice before calling it :) Entities that can be soft deleted have a Delete method.

Comment: `IQueryable<T>` do not belong in repositories. Read some other questions here at SO about why.

Comment: Thanks for the hint @jgauffin, a link to a specific question that exposes your point would be helpful.

Comment: http://blog.gauffin.org/2013/01/repository-pattern-done-right/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't know if it's wise to assume that if insertion, for instance,
>   works for Foo entities it will also work for others

No, you can't assume this. What if some entity do not have correct mapping? What if you forgot to define `DbSet<Bar>` on your `DbContext`? If you want to be completely sure, you should test all methods of all concrete repositories.

> however testing for each has an added overhead in terms of test
>   creation and maintenance

Correct. That's why instead of writing integration tests for repositories only, write acceptance tests for your application. You will exercise whole stack and concrete repositories will be involved.

Comment: I see what you mean with the acceptance tests; however this application is just a DAL, distributed as a library, that other peers will use in their applications to access our system. So there's really not much more to test...